# JSON.NET Root Tag and Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following JSON returning from a Java service

```
  {"Test":{
    "value": 1,
    "message": "This is a test"
  }}
```

I have the following C# class

```
class Test {
    public int value { get; set; }
    public String message { get; set; }
}
```

However, because the root tag "Test" is returned I cannot directly deserialize this with

```
Test deserializedTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(jsonString);
```

I find I have to wrap the the Test class inside another class for this to work. Is there an easy way to avoid this other than

```
JToken root = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JToken testToken = root["Test"];
Test deserializedTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(testToken.toString());
```

Most of the services I'm calling can return an Exception object as well. I figured I'd read the "root" tag of the JSON to determine how to deserialize the object.

How do I get the first root tag and/or is there a better, more elegant method to handle exceptions from a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a wrapper type you can use an anonymous type:

```
var test = 
  JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content, new { Test = new Test()}).Test;
```

If you have more properties, like an exception, it's probably better to create a wrapper type.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and really wanted to get rid of this 'container'. I found this solution, though you need to use an extra string to find the root object:

```
// Container I wanted to discard
public class TrackProfileResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

// Code for discarding it
var jObject = JObject.Parse(s);
var jToken = jObject["response"];
var response = jToken.ToObject<Response>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply write a wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize to this wrapper and fetch the `Test` instance through the `Test` property:

```
Test deserializedTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(jsonString).Test;
```

Answer (score 2):

The response is actually an object that contains the `Test` object. So your object model should look the same. And since the response can contain an exception, you should reflect that too:

```
class Response
{
    public Test Test { get; set; }
    public JObject Exception { get; set; }
}
```

This assumes you don't know how will the `Exception` look like. If you do, use a concrete type instead of `JObject`. You can then process the `Response` object based on whether `Exception` is `null`.

Comment: I think this might actually work nicely if I make it generic object (for the Test object).  This is a very simple way to parse one or the other objects.  Thank you